# comparing user inputs in array to make sure they dont have the same name in java

Tags: java

What am I missing it keeps, coming back false on the first try. What do I need to change to make sure it scans to get rid of duplicates.

```
        final int numPassengers = 4;
        final int numShips = 2;
        boolean input = false;
        String[] travelerNames = new String[4];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numPassengers; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Enter traveler name ");
            do {
                travelerNames[i] = scanner.nextLine();
                if(travelerNames[i].equals(travelerNames[i])) {
                    System.out.println("Names cannot match enter new name!");
                    input = false;
                    scanner.next();
                }
                else {
                    
                    input = true;
                }
            } while(!input);    
            System.out.println(travelerNames[i]);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please describe in more detail, what input you are entering, what output you expect and what output you currently get. On first glance, this line here `if(travelerNames[i].equals(travelerNames[i]))` is definitely incorrect, since you compare the same values. If you try to check if the name read by the input is contained in the array, then the control flow is wrong. It should be 1) read input, 2) loop the array and check each array value for equality with the read input.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use an arraylist.
Arraylist has a method called contains.

```
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.next();

    if(names.contains(input)){
        System.out.println("Name is duplicated");
    }
    else {
        names.add(input);
    }
```

I hope i could help you with your Problem

Comment: if else statement would go into my for loop and the rest would go up top

Comment: No Loop is need. names.contais will iterate over the Arraylist. If you want multiple inputs you can consider taking the part from String input including the else statement in a while loop if this solves your Problem please consider to mark the Answer as Soloution

Answer (score 0):

`travelerNames[i] = scanner.nextLine();` **Whoops**... too late, it's already within the Array and it's in there before you get to check and see if it has been previously entered. Don't save a step here by popping the name into the Array right away, put the name into a String variable first then traverse the Array to see if that name already exists, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPassengers; ++i) {
    String name = "";
    while(name.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print("Enter traveler name #" + (i + 1) + ": -> ");
        name = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if (name.isEmpty() || name.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Name Supplied! (" 
                             + name + ") Try again...\n");
            name = "";
            continue;
        }
        // Is the name already within the travelerNames[] Array?
        for (String nme : travelerNames) {
            if (nme != null && nme.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry! The name '" + name 
                         + "' already exists! Try again...\n");
                name = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Everything seems OK so add the name to the Array.
    travelerNames[i] = name;
}
    
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The names contained within the Array:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(travelerNames));
```